# how to build ffmpeg shared libraries without version suffix

Tags: android, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

is there a way i can configure to build ffmpeg shared libraries for android without version number suffixes? im able to build with different options but always get files like "libavcodec.so.57". i would need the libraries without suffixes like "libavcodec.so". i thought the option "--disable-symver" would do the trick but unfortunately it didn't. the problem is that i have a library (.so file) that depends on ffmpeg shared libraries without suffixes and therefore can't load those im getting built.
i have followed mostly the instructions [here](http://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

asking questions leads always to finding answers. that's why i was successful, digging into the make files helped. do the following:

- run your configuration
- find "config.mak"
- change

  SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION=$(SLIBNAME).$(LIBVERSION)
  SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR=$(SLIBNAME).$(LIBMAJOR)

  to:

  SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION=$(SLIBNAME)
     SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR=$(SLIBNAME)
- change

  SLIB_INSTALL_NAME=$(SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION)
  SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS=$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR) $(SLIBNAME)

  to:

  SLIB_INSTALL_NAME=$(SLIBNAME)
  SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS=
- run "make" or "make -j$(nproc)"
- "make install"

now you will have shared libraries without suffixes.
you can check their dependencies by
"readelf -d somefile.so"

Comment: I needed to do this for Linux. Instead of modifying config.mak I modified the configure script to handle the library names for Linux the same way it does for Android.

Answer (score 4):

No need to change config.mak

Just add **--target-os=android** to configure call

My example

```
NDK=${HOME}/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle
ABI=arm

./configure \
    --arch=$ABI \
    --target-os=android \
    --disable-everything \
    --disable-symver \
    --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --enable-pic \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --prefix=../build/$ABI \
    --cross-prefix=$NDK/toolchains/$ABI-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/$ABI-linux-androideabi- \
    --sysroot=$NDK/platforms/android-26/arch-$ABI \
    --extra-cflags="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -fPIC -DANDROID" \
    --extra-ldflags="" \
    || exit 1

    make clean
    make -j4 || exit 1
    make install || exit 1
```

Comment: This is a great answer. No need to maintain patches. No version numbers at all generated for target-os=android

Comment: how about build for linux? i want ffmpeg run in my app without exec ffmpeg in